# Custom tableview(cell) with checkmark

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to do an app like a to-do app with a  tableview. When I hit the add button (system provided by `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton`) a new tableview appears and a list with given items (provided by an entity of coreData).
Now I want to set by a touch in a cell a checkmark and at the end I want to press the "save" button. For taking all selected (checked items) in the first tableview.

I thought  to do it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
But when I scroll up and down I get checkmarks even in cells that I didn t checked. then I tried the following code:

in`cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.detailObejct = (dataOfEntity[indexPath.row])
if checked[indexPath.row] == false {

    cell.accessoryType = .None
}
else if checked[indexPath.row] == true {

    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
}
```

and in

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            checked[indexPath.row] = false
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            checked[indexPath.row] = true
        }
}
```

but when I run that code I get an error that says array index out of range. The array is declared as

```
var checked = [Bool]()
```

Comment: at what point are you getting index out of bounds crash??

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not taking into account the size of your original dataSource.

You either need to instantiate a dictionary for your checked variable,

```
var checked = Dictionary<Int, Bool>()
```

to track the index inside your original dataSource.

Or instantiate an array with a default size and value

```
var checked : Array<Bool>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // You need the size of your data at this point
    checked = [Bool](count: dataSource.count, repeatedValue: false)
}
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to help.

Comment: Now it works. I had to change some code, e.g. if checkmark is set not to set   false, instead i removed the item in dict. But your hind to set a dict instead of setting an array made it.

Comment: Great! Glad I can help.

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha you are not adding any elements to your checked array I mean it has 0 elements but you are trying to take out an item in the data source method so initialise the checked array with all false values since initially no rows are selected,

```
for _ in 0...tableItems.count{ //tableItems should be your data source count
  checked.append(false)
}
```

I tried the same and everything works fine for me, add the above statement in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dsieczko I changed some details in my code:

```
cell.detailObejct = (dataOfEntity[indexPath.row])
cell.accessoryType = .None // THIS IS MANDATORY
if checked[indexPath.row] == false {

    cell.accessoryType = .None
}
else if checked[indexPath.row] == true {

    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
}
```

and the did select looks like:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            //checked[indexPath.row] = false // this line removes now the entry instead of setting it only to false
checked[indexPath.row] = nil
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            checked[indexPath.row] = true
        }
}
```

and of cause the dict:

```
var checked = Dictionary<Int, Bool>()
```